# matter of params in function call

Tags: javascript

is it possible in javascript-vue.js to **call a method by assigning it a different number of parameters than what it was in function definition** ? (greater or lesser)
I came with backend background "java" yet whenever the call isn't the same I get "*The method X(int, int) is not applicable for the arguments*"
but it seem to be feasable in js, any confirmation/explanation ?

Comment: Use typescript ... It will provide compiletime type-safety ...

Comment: If you provide less arguments than the declared parameters, the excess parameters are `undefined`. If you provide more arguments, the excess ones are ignored.